# Can't remove space from beginning of variable

Tags: shell-script, shell, mkdir, lsblk

I am trying to crate a folder with the label and uuid of a media device plugged in as its name, on another flash drive which I am using to log.
I have the following code:

```
LOGDEVICELABEL=FLASHDRIVENAME
MD=`lsblk -I 8 -o label,uuid -n|sed -e '/^$/ d' -e '/^$LOGDEVICELABEL.*$/ d'`
MDLOGDIR=/media/$LOGDEVICELABEL/Log/$MD
mkdir $MDLOGDIR
```

The problem is that the value pf the variable `$MD` has a space in the beginning which I cannot get rid of. That space causes mkdir to treat `/media/$LOGDEVICELABEL/Log/` and `$MD`as two separate arguements.

I tried:

```
MDLOGDIR=`sed 's/ // g' <<</media/$LOGDEVICELABEL/Log/$MD`
```

Which only removes the space between the UUID and the Label (which is also necessary) but does not remove the space between `/media/$LOGDEVICELABEL/Log/` and `$MD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I'll do is use `echo` to strip unwanted whitespace.  In this context, it's important to omit any quotes:

```
LOGDEVICELABEL=FLASHDRIVENAME
MD=$(lsblk -I 8 -o label,uuid -n|sed -e '/^$/ d' -e '/^$LOGDEVICELABEL.*$/ d')
MD=$(echo $MD) # <-- This line
MDLOGDIR=/media/$LOGDEVICELABEL/Log/$MD
mkdir $MDLOGDIR
```

The shell invokes the `echo` command and supplies it with a series of tokens, and the `echo` command prints those tokens separated by a space character.  This has the effect of (1) skipping leading and trailing whitespace and (2) converting one or more whitespace characters between tokens to a single space.

My use of `$(...)` instead of the back-tick version in this context is equivalent to the back-tick version.  Generally I find this version easier to read.  It also has the nice benefit that it can be nested (`$(...$(...))`) where the back-tick version cannot.

Comment: Can you explain why that worked vs what I had tried? Also, what is the advantage of $() notation that you used vs the `` that I used. Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't sed take care of the trailing whitespace (or RudiC's answer) work? Is it a different type of whitespace?

Comment: To be clear, I'm not claiming that others' answers won't work.  The answer that I provided here is one possible solution.

Comment: I tried them, they don't work. Do you know why?

Comment: It could be the number of whitespace characters; the `lsblk` output is preceeded by more than one space.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use "parameter expansion" like

```
MDLOGDIR=/media/$LOGDEVICELABEL/Log/${MD# }
MDLOGDIR=/media/$LOGDEVICELABEL/Log/${MD/ }
```

or extend the `sed` like

```
s /^ //
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Neither worked for me.

Comment: `MD=" Josef"`
`echo ">$MD<"`
`> Josef<`
`echo ">${MD# }<"`
`>Josef<`
`echo ">${MD/ }<"`
`>Josef<`